# How to Connect to kafka from python using truststore file?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I have `properties.config` file and `kafka.client.truststore.jsk` and I can easily get data from kafka with `kafka-console-consumer` in console using :

```sh
kafka-console-consumer --topic test-topic --group group-id --bootstrap-server server:port --consumer.config config.properties
```

In config.properties file I have :

```
sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
sasl_jaas_config='''org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username="sasl_username" \
password="sasl_password";'''
ssl_truststore_location='kafka.client.truststore.jks'
ssl_truststore_password='truststore_password'
```

But I want receive and process these data in python. So using `keytool` I convert jsk file to `CARoot.pem` and `certificate.pem` and use them in python-confluent-kafka :

```py
consumer_config = {
            'bootstrap.servers': server:port,
            'group.id': group_id,
            'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
            'enable.auto.commit': 'false',
            'max.poll.interval.ms': '86400000',
            'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
            'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
            'ssl.ca.location':'CARoot.pem',
            'ssl.certificate.location':'certificate.pem',
            'sasl.username': 'sasl_username',
            'sasl.password': 'sasl_password'
        }
consumer = Consumer(consumer_config)
consumer.subscribe([test-topic])
```

But what i see in the console is :

```
%3|1653299842.609|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-12| [thrd:sasl_ssl://server:port/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://server:port/bootstrap: SASL authentication error: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password (after 179ms in state AUTH_REQ)
```

I expect to see data in output same as `kafka-console-consumer`.

I try pykafka and python-kafka too. But There is no difference.

Note : I convert jsk to pem using [this](https://dev.to/adityakanekar/connecting-to-kafka-cluster-using-ssl-with-python-k2e) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`jsk` to `pem` convertion was correct. Problem was weird, my sasl_password contains `\` It worked fine in `confing.properties` but not in python code. I removed `\` and it solved.